# Retrieve Access .mdb database password using C#

Tags: c#, ms-access

building an c# application that reads access data base file.
Each database will have a different password on it. At present I am using Access Passview http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/accesspv.html (freeware) to read the password but i want to be able to automate it so i can assign it to a string for the OLEDB connection string.
(screen shot of the exe when executed)

[image]

The exe can be run from the command line, which is what I have tried to implement in my application

```
    var proc = new Process
    {
        StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = "accesspv.exe",
            Arguments = _filePath, 
            UseShellExecute = false,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            CreateNoWindow = true,     
        }
    };

    proc.Start();
    while (!proc.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
    {
        string line = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        Console.WriteLine(line);
       _password2016 = line;
   }
```

This does not work for me as the access passview exe runs as normal and the password doesnt display in the console.

My main question would be 
1. Is it possible to read the password as assign it to a variable for my connection string?
2. Have it so the accesspv.exe runs in the background so the end user doesnt see it?

thanks.

Comment: If its opensource, you could make a console version.... otherwise you need to screenscrape the password out of there, as no it wouldnt pick up the words as its not writing to standard output..

Comment: sorry, my mistake, its just freeware, not open source

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The source code for that util is available on the website [here](http://www.nirsoft.net/vb/accpass.html). You can just write the same code in C#.

```
public class Program
{
    private static readonly byte[] XorBytes = {
        0x86, 0xFB, 0xEC, 0x37, 0x5D, 0x44, 0x9C, 0xFA, 0xC6,
        0x5E, 0x28, 0xE6, 0x13, 0xB6, 0x8A, 0x60, 0x54, 0x94
    };

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var filePath = args[0];
        var fileBytes = new byte[256];

        using (var fileReader = File.OpenRead(filePath))
        {
            fileReader.Read(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
        }

        var passwordBytes = XorBytes
            .Select((x, i) => (byte) (fileBytes[i + 0x42] ^ x))
            .TakeWhile(x => x != 0);
        var password = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(passwordBytes.ToArray());

        Console.WriteLine($"Password is \"{password}\"");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Note to future readers: As stated in the original VB6 source code, "It works only with Access 95 or 97 [database files]."

Comment: Thanks Matt, thats a huge help!